# How do I package an application to submit to the MyApps portal?

Tags: software-center, application-development, packaging, application-submission

I'm trying to [submit](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/) my [app](https://launchpad.net/~umpirsky/+archive/revision-monitor) to the MyApps portal.

I really don't get it what I should submit, source code or deb package? If source, in which format, whole app as zip, tar.gz...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll also point you to [Uploading your app](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/my-apps-packages/).

Ideally, you should submit a **Debian source package**. A Debian source package consists of 3 files (with extensions `.dsc`, `diff.gz`, `orig.tar.gz`), which you should put in a compressed archive (a tarball, zip file, rar...) and upload into [My Apps](http://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com). This will allow reviewers to easily test and publish your app.

However, there are some important caveats:

- If your app is **commercial or proprietary software**: we still recommend uploading a Debian source package, but if you are not experienced in packaging you can also upload either a binary Debian package (`.deb`), your source code in a compressed archive, your binary executables and all files needed to run your app in a compressed archive, and the commercial packagers will package and publish it for you.
- If your app is **Free Software and gratis**: we recommend using a Personal Packaging Archive (PPA). You can specify the location of your PPA in the '*Any additional notes for the application reviewer*' text box in the Overview tab of your app's entry in My Apps. You can also learn more about PPAs in the packaging section of the [Ubuntu App Developer Site](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging) (*)

(*) Sorry for the confusion here, we've recently switched to recommending PPAs for Free Software gratis apps, and the web UI might be a it confusing.

Answer (score 3):

See [Uploading your app](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/my-apps-packages/).

Ideally you should submit a `.deb` package. For commercial applications you can alternatively submit a `.tar.gz` with source code or a binary, or specify a PPA for free software.

Comment: Thanks, how can I specify a PPA for free software?

Comment: The PPA line is specified in comments. See @David Planella answer for more details

Comment: A debian source package is probably preferable to a deb. Especially if its architecture-dependant.